# Create pages with different permissions for different types of users?

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create pages with different permissions' views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184202/how-to-create-pages-with-different-permissions-views)

I am just a beginner and can not understand the code. Can somebody help me? Is there any other way to do it?

[How to create pages with different permissions' views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184202/how-to-create-pages-with-different-permissions-views)

The admin would create different users with different viewing and editing rights. Whenever a user visits a page, the program checks the database to see if he has the proper rights. Only than is he able to view the data.

All I could think of was to create a table where rights can be stored as 0 or 1.

But now that seems just stupid and naive.

Is there any other way?

Comment: if you can't understand the code, start by learning the language and frameworks. Step by steps. Do not try to reinvent to wheel or produce messy code, just because you missed something.

Comment: @SteveB I think that sometimes individuals can explain things more clearly than a book. That was the only reason I posted the code here. Sorry if some rule was broken.